# Using ftp_fget using SFTP / phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm currently having a horrible time with SFTP.
Is there a way to use ftp_fget using SFTP?

I'm using the phpseclibrary, but it only offers their own implementation of `$sftp->get()` howver I would like `$sftp->fget();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest Git version (ie. later than 0.3.7), instead of `$sftp->fget()`, you can do something like this:

```
$fp = fopen('filename.ext', 'w');
$sftp->get('file_to_download.ext', $fp);
fclose($fp);
```

You could also alternatively use Net/SFTP/Stream.php . eg.

```
$resFile = fopen("sftp://{$resSFTP}/".$filename, 'w');
$srcFile = fopen("/home/myusername/".$filename, 'r');
$writtenBytes = stream_copy_to_stream($srcFile, $resFile);
fclose($resFile);
fclose($srcFile);
```